# Accessing a label from outside a function

Tags: c, assembly, kernel

The code:

```
/* ctsw.c : context switcher
 */

#include <kernel.h>

static void *kstack;
extern int set_evec(int, long);

/* contextswitch - saves kernel context, switches to proc */
enum proc_req contextswitch(struct proc_ctrl_blk *proc) {
  enum proc_req call;

  kprintf("switching to %d\n", getpid(proc));

  asm volatile("pushf\n"          // save kernel flags
               "pusha\n"          // save kernel regs
               "movl %%esp, %0\n" // save kernel %esp
               "movl %1, %%esp\n" // load proc %esp
               "popa\n"           // load proc regs (from proc stack)
               "iret"             // switch to proc
               : "=g" (kstack)
               : "g" (proc->esp)
               );

_entry_point:
  asm volatile("pusha\n"          // save proc regs
               "movl %%esp, %0\n" // save proc %esp
               "movl %2, %%esp\n" // restore kernel %esp
               "movl %%eax, %1\n" // grabs syscall from process
               "popa\n"           // restore kernel regs (from kstack)
               "popf"             // restore kernel flags
               : "=g" (proc->esp), "=g" (call)
               : "g" (kstack)
               );
  kprintf("back to the kernel!\n");

  return call;
}

void contextinit() {
  set_evec(49, (long)&&_entry_point);
}
```

It's a context switcher for a small, cooperative, non-preemptive kernel. `contextswitch()` is called by `dispatcher()` with the stack pointer of the process to load. Once %esp and other general purpose registers have been loaded, `iret` is called and the user process starts running.

I need to setup an interrupt to return to the point in `contextswitch()` after the `iret` so I can restore the kernel context and return the value of the syscall to `dispatcher()`.

How can I access the memory address of `_entry_point` from outside the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little while playing around with GCC, I've got an answer.

Dropping down to assembly silences GCC warnings about unused labels.

So,

```
_entry_point:
```

is replaced with

```
asm volatile("_entry_point:");
```

and

```
void contextinit() {
  set_evec_(49, &&_entry_point);
}
```

is replaced with

```
void contextinit() {
  long x;
  asm("movl $_entry_point, %%eax\n"
      "movl %%eax, %0": "=g" (x) : : "%eax");
  set_evec(49, x);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Switch the implementation of the function around: make it look like this:

- Context switch from user to kernel;
- Call into kernel routines;
- Context switch back from kernel to user.

Then you can just set up the interrupt to run the function from the start.  There will need to be a global pointer for "the current user process" - to switch between processes, the kernel code that's run by "Call into kernel routines" just changes that variable to point at a different process.

You will need one special case - for the initial switch from kernel to user mode, for the initial process that's running after boot.  After that though, the above function should be able to handle it.

Comment: This is a good idea, and if I didn't already have the dispatcher and process control code already written assuming the other model, I might use it.

Answer (score 1):

Besides using inline assembly to access the _entry_point, you can also define it as a function, like:

```
asm volatile("_entry_point:");

void contextinit() {
  extern void _entry_point();
  set_evec(49, (long)&_entry_point);
}
```